# How can I see the exact path of each library file being linked into my Visual Studio 2013 C++ project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, linker, static-libraries

I'm having a tough time chasing down what appears to be a library file mismatch.  I recently upgraded to a **new SDK** that my app uses and I believe I have an **old library file** lying around that is causing me a headache.

I know I can unload the VC++ project file and open it in edit mode to find out what the macro symbols for the library and additional dependency paths expand out to.  But it would really help to get a full list showing every lib file linked into my app with the full path shown.

Note, I am **not getting any errors at link time**.  Instead, I'm getting some **subtle errors at runtime** that indicate an old library file may be to blame.

Is there a way to see that information?

Comment: Check out Dependency Walker.

Comment: Linker properties/General/Show Progress.  Set to  either **Displays Some Progress Messages** or **Display All Progress Messages**